# How do you update a git repository from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I am new to Visual studio and am wondering how do you update a folder's contents stored in your local system into a specific Github repository?

I would also like to know how to update the folders present into the repository too.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out finally, we need to "Stage changes" by clicking the "+" icon in the "Changes" section in the Git changes window (Accessed via clicking the "Commit or stash" option in the Git menu), then "Commit staged and Sync" in the combo box above it...

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on the github website. Take a look at: https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/publishing-an-existing-project-to-github.md

Comment: Thanks @Zserbinator, but this only works for pushing the github repository initially. What do we need to do to, say, update a new file added to the folder after the commit has taken place? (How do you amend the already existing repository from Visual Studio?)

Comment: I found out a way, thanks for the help @Zserbinator!